# Slick js dont work with my html and i've check my js and my css i dont understand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm creating my new website and I want to put carrousel in the site,
I found a jquery framework called Slick.js and I want to use it on my site 
I've followed the tutorial in the site I try and I see very strange thing arrows of the carrousel don't change their position when I put text or image with different width or weight.

I thought the problem was here because I've created few conflicts with my CSS and my HTML so I tried to remove my CSS code and slick js do another strange thing, arrows disappear and I don't know why I thought it was because I used CSS code to resize my pictures but when I use text slick js do the same I seek in google and I tried `box-sizing: border-box` and  after I thought it was because I created a CSS rule with `*{margin : 0; padding : 0;}` but its not working, I bought a new framework but I absolutely want to use slick js because I need to use slider syncing I don't what I must try I'm lost thanks for your help

I use jsDelivr to put content in my site

I paste the code in code pen https://codepen.io/jouj1234/pen/aeYrjz

**HTML of my slider:**

```html
<div class="firstsectionpic">
    <div class="firstsectionpicslick">
        <div>12</div>
        <div>13</div>
        <div>14</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I looked in CSS and js tools in firefox but I don't see anything for firefox my site work normally

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if i'm answering your problem correctly, so i'll add it as a comment. If you literally just mean the arrows sitting outside of their container is the problem.. It's because you're loading in `slick-theme.css` which adds a `right:-25px;` and `left:-25px;` to the `.slick-next` and `.slick-prev` classes, removing these will make the arrows sit inside their container again. If this was not the problem then please provide more context.

Comment: The only thing you are sliding in that codepen are those div elements that contain just the numbers, those are only as high as one line of text demands. Not sure in what way you expect the outcome to be any different here? Put more content into those elements, then the arrows move down accordingly.

Comment: Misorude, arrows dont care if its a picture or text i can put more text arrows stay here , but my answer was 1 how can i put arrows arround my text or my picture and why i cant see the left arrow thanks for your help, Aaron, im trying to modify the css file thanks im going to answer to you when i could try thanks

Comment: Aaron McGuire, i tried to modify the css theme file,
I removed lines but its the same, thanks for your answer

Comment: Arrows disapears when i remove those lines, i dont Understand anything with slickjs